# Pushing a navigation controller is not supported in swift , Move from Modal to Navigation

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, uinavigationcontroller

Similar like `iPhone` phoneBook, I want make view like VC(tableView) -> Modal -> navigationView. But I'm having some problems:

```
//vc(tableView)
@objc func addBtnClick(sender: UIButton){
    let childVC = InformationView()
    let fakeRootView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: childVC)
    self.present(fakeRootView, animated: true){
        print("rootView CompletionHandler")
    }
```

Then save infomation in `InformationView` using `realm`:

```
@objc
func saveBtnClick(sender: UIButton){
    content.phoneName = self.nameField.text!
    content.phoneNum = self.phoneNumber.text!
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(content, update: .all)
    }
    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    table.tableView.reloadData()
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    navInfoViewLoad()

func navInfoViewLoad(){
        let childVC = contentView
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(childVC, animated: true)

    }
```

After pressing saveBtnClick, I want to move to `contentView`. But I am getting an error:

> Thread 1: Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

What is the problem?

Comment: You don't push `UINavigationController`, you present them using `present`.

Comment: if i use present, can i make it sameView, like navigationView,seems like.. it have navigationbar.. ?